# Odoo TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, odoo, amazon-rds, odoo-12

When i open Point of sale session the screen goes completely black and I am getting this weird error in console after i enable a custom module. But this error disappears when i am in debug=assets mode.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined
http://example.com/web/content/479-09c3762/point_of_sale.assets.js.pagespeed.jm.mrdXf0Eas7.js:5
Traceback:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined
    at Class.show_popup (http://example.com/web/content/479-09c3762/point_of_sale.assets.js.pagespeed.jm.mrdXf0Eas7.js:5:21802)
    at Class.select_user (http://example.com/web/content/479-09c3762/point_of_sale.assets.js.pagespeed.jm.mrdXf0Eas7.js:6:298)
    at Class.click_username (http://example.com/web/content/479-09c3762/point_of_sale.assets.js.pagespeed.jm.mrdXf0Eas7.js:3:15944)
    at HTMLSpanElement.<anonymous> (http://example.com/web/content/479-09c3762/point_of_sale.assets.js.pagespeed.jm.mrdXf0Eas7.js:3:15873)
    at HTMLSpanElement.dispatch (http://example.com/web/content/474-fda256b/web.assets_common.js.pagespeed.jm.Rc9A_s9iaL.js:10:21111)
    at HTMLSpanElement.elemData.handle (http://example.com/web/content/474-fda256b/web.assets_common.js.pagespeed.jm.Rc9A_s9iaL.js:10:15621)
Ok
```

There is also a following message before this error:

```
Tour Manager is ready.  running_tour=null
```

Comment: Do you have a custom js file in custom addons ? If yes then the problem is with the xpath you are giving, override some other xpath from default code that’s used in that view and ‘add’ your js path inside it. For some reason custom js is not loading inside that view without debug = assets

Comment: If you added any new file/module related to pos , need to restart the server or give permission to the file